# Django-Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: django, postgresql

There some questions related to this but no answers are helped.
I often come accross errors like that but cannot figure out what causes problems. My projects has been running fine but suddenly all of them which using postgresql are stopped, giving following error.

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
     self.connect()
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
     return func(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
     return func(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
     connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 728, in connect
     raise ex.with_traceback(None)
 psycopg.OperationalError: connection is bad: No such file or directory
         Is the server running locally and accepting
         connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
     response = get_response(request)
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
     with self._recreate_cm():
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 198, in __enter__
     if not connection.get_autocommit():
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 464, in get_autocommit
     self.ensure_connection()
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
     return func(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
     self.connect()
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
     self.connect()
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
     return func(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
     return func(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
     connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
   File "/var/www/crm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 728, in connect
     raise ex.with_traceback(None)
 django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection is bad: No such file or directory
         Is the server running locally and accepting
         connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

status of postgresql says:

```bash
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

```bash
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2023-10-19 14:15:37 +05; 1 weeks 3 days ago
   Main PID: 1625 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 72259)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
```

after restarting postgresql server:

```bash
sudo systemctl status 'postgresql*'
```

```bash
● postgresql@12-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 12-main
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-10-30 10:30:46 +05; 5min ago
    Process: 1332355 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 12-main start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1332371 (postgres)
      Tasks: 15 (limit: 72259)
     Memory: 182.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@12-main.service
             ├─1332371 /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
             ├─1332375 postgres: 12/main: checkpointer
             ├─1332376 postgres: 12/main: background writer
             ├─1332377 postgres: 12/main: walwriter
             ├─1332378 postgres: 12/main: autovacuum launcher
             ├─1332379 postgres: 12/main: stats collector
             ├─1332380 postgres: 12/main: logical replication launcher
             ├─1332382 postgres: 12/main: proactive proactive 127.0.0.1(34858) idle
             ├─1332383 postgres: 12/main: proactive saveanybot 127.0.0.1(34870) idle
             ├─1332412 postgres: 12/main: proactive poytaxt-bot [local] idle
             ├─1333700 postgres: 12/main: proactive crm [local] idle
             ├─1335713 postgres: 12/main: proactive crm [local] idle
             ├─1335732 postgres: 12/main: proactive crm [local] idle
             ├─1336204 postgres: 12/main: proactive saveanybot 127.0.0.1(51374) idle
             └─1336207 postgres: 12/main: proactive poytaxt-bot [local] idle

● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2023-10-30 10:30:46 +05; 5min ago
    Process: 1332397 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1332397 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

What is the main reason for such errors happening ?

Comment: Look the database server's log file.  Which is probably somewhere like "/var/log/postgresql/*".